# Can I store multiple images paths like this in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an app in which i want to store multiple images paths on same user id in sqlite database may be like comma seperated. How can i do this.

I want the table like this in sqlite database:

[image: you can check the table structure here]

Comment: You **could**. But it's a **worst practice** to store lists in that way. You'd better **normalize** your database structure.

Comment: Agree with @Rotwang

Comment: yes, normalize it by adding the "images" table

Comment: You can save `JSONArray` in that column if you want. Preferably try `Realm` https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/ But ya as said before by others, it is bad practise, it affects a lot performance wise.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can create two tables.
MainTable having following columns:

1. id (Primary key)
2. profile_image

ImageDescription Table having following columns:

1. id (Primary key)
2. main_table_id (Foreign key)
3. desc_images

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go with a table for image paths with a row per image. A user table with a row per user and a third link table with a row per image/id/usage combination.

e.g.
**Images**

- _id
- imagepath

**User table**

- _id
- Username etc

**ImageUserRef table (Primary key made up of all three fields)**

- userref (*id of the user*)
- imageref (*id of the image*)
- usage

---

Your data would/could represented by

**Images table**

- Row1    _id=**1**    imagepath=**/pics/1.jpg**
- Row2    _id=**2**    imagepath=**/pics/2.jpg**
- Row3    _id=**3**    imagepath=**/pics/5.jpg**
- Row4    _id=**4**    imagepath=**/pics/7.jpg**
- Row5    _id=**5**    imagepath=**/pics/8.jpg**
- Row6    _id=**6**    imagepath=**/pics/9.jpg**

**User table**

- Row1    _id=**1**    username=whatever
- Row2    _id=**2**    username=somethingelse

**ImageUserRef table**

- arow     userref=**1** imageref=**1**     usage=**desc**
- arow     userref=**1** imageref=**2**     usage=**desc**
- arow     userref=**1** imageref=**3**     usage=**profile**
- arow     userref=**2** imageref=**4**     usage=**desc**
- arow     userref=**2** imageref=**5**     usage=**desc**
- arow     userref=**2** imageref=**6**     usage=**profile**

Note I'd represent usage with a number and use a numeric field rather than text.

Comment: why 1:1 relationship between Images <-> ImageUserRef ? why not to combine them?

Comment: Just going by data provided, of course you could have `userref=1 imageref=7 usage=desc`

Comment: i mean that it is enough to add just one additional table, not two, see Chirag Prajapati's answer above

Comment: It is, but 3 tables gives more flexibility, e.g. if profile were allowed multiple images.

Comment: Additionally it could be more efficient as path (text field) occurs just once per image (e.g. the same path could be stored multiple times using the 2 table method).

Comment: ... sounds so enlightening.

Comment: This is the "standard" normalized way. The preferred one. Two tables and a lookup table to join them.

Comment: You require a 3rd table to normalize only when there is many-to-many(i,e one-to-many both ways) relationship between the original two table structures.

Comment: If there is a one-to-many relation then you just need to put the foreign key in the table which has the many relationship, so that proper linking can take place between the two table structures.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two tables as defined below rather than store multi values by comma separated

[image: Profile Table]

[image: Image Table]